# Remove empty nodes with no attributes from XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Input XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>
<TEST ID="1" DATA="DATE"/>
<TEST/>
<TEST2 ID="3" COLUMN="VALUE"/>
</dataset>
```

Desired Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>
<TEST ID="1" DATA="DATE"/>
<TEST2 ID="3" COLUMN="VALUE"/>
</dataset>
```

Current applied XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="*[not(child::node())]"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Current Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>
</dataset>
```

What could be the condition to be applied, to achieve output without empty `'<TEST/>'` node in result.

Answer (score 3):

Check following Code

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[not(@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction()) and normalize-space()='']"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep elements that have either child nodes or attributes, then change this:

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(child::node())]"/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(node() or @*)]"/>
```

---

Note that `child` is the default axis, so `child::` can be omitted.